# SVN post-commit - permission denied to .svn/lock

Tags: svn, post-commit-hook

After commiting, I get a `post-commit hook failed` error:

```
svn: Can't open file '.svn/lock': Permission denied
```

Oddly, my post-commit hook file runs perfectly fine on it's own, just not when called from an actual commit.

Now, the post-commit file ends up `svn update`ing another working copy, so I assume the error is in this working copy.

When I go into `.svn` on this working copy, there is no `locks` file/directory. This is presumably why the script fails.

This is my post-commit file:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

cd /var/www
/usr/bin/svn update
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> my post-commit hook file runs perfectly fine on it's own, just not when called from an actual commit.

My crystal ball tells me your svn hooks are ran by a different user, that doesn't have write rights to the folder it needs to create the lock in.

Comment: ah, I got it, `chmod` does't do hidden files by default!

Comment: indeed, I also humbly remind you about the limit before you can accept an answer :)

Comment: I thought it was 15 minutes, whatever, doesn't hurt, I guess. Glad I could help.

Comment: Note that it may not just be the file itself, but any upstream folder containing the file you are trying to access!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have problem with the permissions may be. Try,

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) YourDirectory
sudo chmod -R u+w YourDirectory
```